# Repeater datasource Connection not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repeater

Here is my Code Structure.

**Repeater Markup**:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RPMenu" DataSource='<%# Menues.GetAllMainMenu() %>'>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <%# Eval("MenuName") %><br />

          <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RPMenuUnder" DataSource='<%# Menues.GetAllMainMenu(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("MenuID"))) %>'>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("MenuName") %><br />
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Menu Class** :

```
public static List<Menu> GetAllMainMenu(int parrentID = 0)
{
    using (Scooterfrøen_Entities db = new Scooterfrøen_Entities())
    {
        return db.Menu.Where(i => i.ParentMenuID == parrentID).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Database table**: 
MenuID | MenuName | MenuDescription | ParrentMenuID | MenuUrl

I have several rows where `ParentMenuID` IS `0` and `NOT NULL`.

But for some reason `Repeater` control does not list anything on the site.

What could be the reason why Repeater control don't show anything?

Comment: what is this class you are using `Scooterfrøen_Entities`?

Comment: Did you debug the code to know if you are returning data?

Comment: @HassanNisar That is my Entity framework connection string to my database.

Comment: I am not sure about this but I guess Class name having symbol (ø) may be not allowed. OK about your `Eval` command in markup, have you tried using `alias` in your query. It seems `MenuName` is having conflict with parent Repeater control.

Answer (score 1):

I think page still requires to bind even though you have provided datasource in markup.
Write `Page.DataBind();` in your page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

**How to Use nested Repeater**:
It seems you have to handle `ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound` event to bind child repeater control.

Checkout this article available [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6140/A-quick-guide-to-using-nested-repeaters-in-ASP-NET).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set values and bind repeater

```
RPMenu.DataSource=<value you want to set>;
RPMenu.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the two existing answers is closest to true.

Rather than run `Page.DataBind()`, which may have unintended side-effects, run `RPMenu.DataBind()` in the `Page_Load` event handler. It will use the `DataSource` which is set in code-front.

The inner Repeater should automatically be bound. You only need to explicitly databind the outermost Repeater.